# ConTeXt: Suppress blank page when text reaches column's end

Tags: page-breaking, context, columns

## Background

When text reaches the end of a column, it triggers inserting a blank page. This does not happen when text reaches the end of a page outside of a columnar environment.

## Problem

In the sample code, `\dorecurse{3}` causes a blank page to appear but `\dorecurse{2}` does not. The only difference is that when set to `3`, additional text is written on the last line of the last column. This scenario results in a blank page.

## Minimum Working Example

Code showing the problem:

```
\showgrid
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\starttext
  \startcolumnset[n=2]
    \input knuth \input lorem \input lorem \input knuth
    \dorecurse{3}{No TV and no beer make Homer something something.}
  \stopcolumnset
\stoptext
```

## Output

Output before text reaches the last line:

[image: Text Before Last Line]

Output after text reaches the last line:

[image: Text At Last Line]

## Question

Any ideas how the blank page can be suppressed?

## Ideas

Suggestions from the mailing list do not appear to suppress the page:

```
\setuppagenumbering[page=no]
\installpagebreakhandler{last}{}
```

## Suppress Eject Page

The `columnset` commands are aliased to `pagegrid` commands, so the following should be equivalent. The output in the following example has some displeasing overlaps, but it nonetheless shows how to eliminate the blank pages. By `\unprotect`ing the `\page_grd_stop` macro, it is possible to redefine the macro to suppress page breaking.

However, this comes with a few side-effects in that some pages may not be written to the final document (i.e., the pages are not exported).

```
\showgrid
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,page=no]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definepagegrid[example][n=3,distance=.05\makeupwidth,page=no]

\setuppagegrid[example:1][width=.4\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:2][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:3][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\setuppagegrid[example:4][width=.40\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:5][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:6][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\unprotect
\def\page_grd_stop{%
  \endgraf % needed, else wrong vsize in one par case
  \vfill % otherwise weird \placenotes[endnotes]
  \page_grd_command_set_vsize % needed
  \penalty\c_page_otr_eject_penalty
  %\page_grd_command_flush_page
  \page_otr_fill_and_eject_page
  \page_grd_command_set_vsize % why here
  \egroup
  \page_otr_command_set_vsize
  \page_otr_command_set_hsize
}
\protect

\starttext
  \startpagegrid[example]
    \input knuth \input lorem \input lorem \input knuth \input lorem
    \dorecurse{3}{No TV and no beer make Homer something something.}
  \stoppagegrid
\stoptext
```

## Version

```
$ context --version
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 1.03
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2019.12.06 19:45
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/context/tex/texmf-context/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkxl
mtx-context     | current version: 2019.12.06 19:45
```

Comment: There is an explicit page break in `\stopcolumnset`: https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/f74c4055713ab52a11d12435eb04040ec6553129/tex/context/base/mkiv/page-cst.mkiv#L199-L201

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Partial Solution

The following code will suppress page breaks when text in a multicolumn environment reaches the end of the last column:

```
\unprotect
\def\page_grd_stop{%
   \endgraf % needed, else wrong vsize in one par case
   \vfill % otherwise weird \placenotes[endnotes]
   \page_grd_command_set_vsize % needed
   \penalty\c_page_otr_eject_penalty
   %\page_grd_command_flush_page
   \page_otr_fill_and_eject_page
   \page_grd_command_set_vsize % why here
   \egroup
   \page_otr_command_set_vsize
   \page_otr_command_set_hsize}
\protect
```

However, the solution comes at a cost. First, this will suppress flushing pages of text that *do not* extend to the last line of the last column of multicolumn text. Second, the following scenario breaks:

```
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\starttext
   \startcolumnset[n=2]
     \dorecurse{100}{Line #1\par}
   \stopcolumnset
\stoptext
```

## Problems

The `columnset` commands are aliased to `pagegrid` commands, so the following should be equivalent. The output in the following example has some displeasing overlaps, but it nonetheless shows how to eliminate the blank pages. By `\unprotect`ing the `\page_grd_stop` macro, it is possible to redefine the macro to suppress page breaking.

```
\showgrid
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,page=no]
\setuplayout[grid=yes]

\definepagegrid[example][n=3,distance=.05\makeupwidth,page=no]

\setuppagegrid[example:1][width=.4\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:2][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:3][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\setuppagegrid[example:4][width=.4\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:5][width=.2\makeupwidth]
\setuppagegrid[example:6][width=.2\makeupwidth]

\unprotect
\def\page_grd_stop{%
  \endgraf % needed, else wrong vsize in one par case
  \vfill % otherwise weird \placenotes[endnotes]
  \page_grd_command_set_vsize % needed
  \penalty\c_page_otr_eject_penalty
  %\page_grd_command_flush_page
  \page_otr_fill_and_eject_page
  \page_grd_command_set_vsize % why here
  \egroup
  \page_otr_command_set_vsize
  \page_otr_command_set_hsize
}
\protect

\starttext
  \startpagegrid[example]
    \input knuth \input lorem \input lorem \input knuth \input lorem
    \dorecurse{3}{No TV and no beer make Homer something something.}
  \stoppagegrid
\stoptext
```

## Additional Details

Fixing this problem so that multicolumns (i.e., page grids) behave like regular pages and other columnar environments will likely require patching ConTeXt itself.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this issue. I have been having the same problem with the pagecolumns environment: whenever the last column on the last page is partially complete, a blank page is added afterward. Your partial solution of redefining the macro does not seem to work in my case, so I imagine that pagecolumns may not be aliased to `pagegrid` commands as columnsets are.

If this issue is distinct enough to warrant a separate question, I would be happy to open a separate question for it and offer an MWE and some further background.

Comment: Joey, consider posting your question to the [users mailing list](https://www.contextgarden.net/ConTeXt_Mailing_Lists). Be sure to provide a minimum working example that illustrates the problem and behaviour. It may be worth noting in the message that there's an implicit page break in `\stopcolumnset`. Having an option to override that behaviour seems reasonable, but will require changing ConTeXt.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! I should have mentioned that I already did post my question (complete with a MWE and some background) to the mailing list about a week ago, and since I hadn't heard anything back since then, I was thinking of asking about it on here, too. That was when I noticed that your question had already covered a very similar issue with columnsets. It may be worthwhile for me to mention your discussion of this issue on the thread I've started on mailing list, though.

Comment: Absolutely, Joey, bump your thread on the mailing list.