# Blank page added after pagecolumns in ConTeXt

Tags: page-breaking, context, columns

This question arose in the comments in [Ragged-bottom footnotes in ConTeXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538775/ragged-bottom-footnotes-in-context); I have since reported the issue to the ConTeXt mailing list, but I have not heard anything back so far, so I decided I should ask about it here as well. If I get an answer either here or on the mailing list, I will share the answer in the other place, to make it more likely that anyone else running into this issue will find a solution.

I am typesetting a document using pagecolumns to ensure that my footnotes
are set ragged-bottom in columns. I have observed some unexpected behavior
whenever the last column on a page is left incomplete: a blank page is
added at the end of the document. A minimal working example follows:

```
\starttext

\startpagecolumns[n=2]

\dorecurse{3}{\par\input zapf}

\stoppagecolumns

\stoptext
```

I typeset this using ConTeXt version 2020.03.10, as released with TeXLive
2020. Notably, if `\dorecurse{3}` is changed to `\dorecurse{2}` or
`\dorecurse{6}` (so that the text ends in the first column of a page), then
there is no problem. The issue is also not limited to one-page documents; if `\dorecurse{3}` is changed to `\dorecurse{8}`, then what would normally be a two-page document is extended to a three-page document. I have tried to fix this by specifying `page=no` in the
`\startpagecolumns` arguments (similar to the fix for section blocks in https://www.contextgarden.net/Empty_page_at_the_end), but it did not change anything.

In several
of the examples (including those for side floats and footnotes) found in the pagecolumns manual (
http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/pagecolumns.pdf), the
addition of a blank page after the end of the environment also
seems to occur. So when the manual says, "We always start at a new page and
end on a new one," does it mean that the blank page is an intended feature of pagecolumns? And
if so, is there any way to disable it? Adding a page break
after the end of the pagecolumns environment makes perfect sense, but an additional empty page is unnecessary. I checked the ConTeXT Garden Wiki for a page on the
`\definepagecolumns` command to get more information on its accepted inputs,
but there doesn't appear to be a page for this command.

This issue is very similar to the one addressed in [ConTeXt: Suppress blank page when text reaches column's end](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519762/context-suppress-blank-page-when-text-reaches-columns-end), where a blank page is added after columnset environments. In that question, the proposed solution is to redefine the \page_grd_stop macro found in page-cst.mkiv. Unfortunately, this does not fix the problem with pagecolumns in my MWE. Are pagecolumns commands aliased to pagegrid commands like columnset commands are, or are they defined somewhere else? I checked page-col.mkiv, but it seems to be too short to be the file that defines pagecolumns behavior.

Is there a fix for this that I'm missing?

Comment: It looks like the place to look for the pagecolumns source code is `page-pcl.mkiv` (https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/page-pcl.mkiv). The definition of `\page_col_stop_yes` seems to have something to do with the issue. If I redefine it in my MWE and comment out the two `\page` calls, then no extra page is added when the text ends in the last column; however, this results in the last page not getting typeset if its text ends in a column before the last one. I think I'm close, but I need to do a bit more experimentation (or get a bit more help) before I have a real answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out an answer thanks to Wolfgang Schuster. As I mentioned in a comment on the question, the pagecolumns source code is located in `page-pcl.mkiv`. In that code, the `\stoppagecolumns` macro has two implementations, `\page_col_stop_yes` and `\page_col_stop_nop`. The choice of which implementation is used is determined by which of two implementations of `\startpagecolumns` (`\page_col_start_yes` and `\page_col_start_nop`) is used. That choice, in turn, is made in the `\page_col_start` macro. The choice depends on the number of columns (i.e., the `n` option for the pagecolumns environment) is more than one, then the "yes" implementation of the start and stop commands is used; otherwise, the "no" implementation is used.

The fix that Wolfgang Schuster proposed was to patch the `\page_col_stop_yes` macro to add a column only if the environment does not end on the last column of the page:

```
\unprotect
\def\page_col_stop_yes
  {%Add a column only if this is not the last column on the page:
  \ifnum\c_page_col_current<\c_page_col_n_of_columns
    \column
  \fi
  \page
  \endgroup
  %\setupoutputroutine[\s!singlecolumn]%
  \page_otr_command_set_vsize
  \page_otr_command_set_hsize
  \page
  \endgroup}
\protect
```

That said, the addition of a blank page appears to be an issue in the code that needs to be fixed, but in the meantime, this patch should work.

Comment: One further note: when I use a two-sided page layout, I've found that it is still necessary in practice to add `\page[no]` at the end of the `pagecolumns` environment to prevent ConTeXt from adding a formatted final page to get an even page count. With `\page[no]`, it will still need to add a page to get an even page count, but the page will correctly have empty formatting (i.e., no headers, page numbers, etc.).